# How to change cursor shape in Vim when entering insert mode with macOS Terminal.app?

Tags: vim, terminal, xterm

I want to change the cursor shape from an underscore to vertical when entering insert mode within VIM running in Terminal.app. (NOTE: I am aware that this is the default behavior under macvim.)

This reference: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes provides instructions on how to do this. For example, the following works with iterm2:

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with Terminal.app (under Lion).

Are there any tricks for this with Terminal.app - or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely certain I've seen an Applescript-based solution in the past but 5 minutes of google didn't bring anything. It was a little barbaric but it seemed to work… IIRC it changed the cursor shape preference on the fly and was triggered with an `autocmd`.

Keep searching, it's somewhere.

Are there any reason why you don't want to use iTerm?

Comment: Thanks for response.  Yes - for now I am using iterm2. The only reason that I would prefer Terminal.app if I could get this to work is pretty minor.  I use an image background (a leather texture for aesthetics).  I find that Terminal.app handles the rendering much better.  iterm2 renders a little choppy with some delays - when for example scrolling through man docs and such.

Comment: I would say that the changing cursor is minor too but *less* minor than the background image rendering issues. I went through a second google session with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a similar problem myself, and found that this answer helped:

https://superuser.com/questions/712098/customize-vim-cursor-style-under-mac-os-x-terminal

When I started running vim inside tmux  (still using terminal) the commands to change the cursor started working!

Tmux is a really cool terminal manager that lets you have multiple terminal windows, tabs, split-screens, you name it, as well as save your sessions. Heres a nice tutorial I used to get it installed and useful:

http://fideloper.com/mac-vim-tmux

Answer (score 0):

OP asked this question in August 2012.  It's very unlikely that Terminal.app supported the ability to change the cursor shape to a vertical bar at that time, because Terminal.app as a general rule provides very few features that are not imitating xterm.  (The undocumented OSC 6 and 7 are the only exception to that rule which comes to mind).

xterm [patch #282](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282) about 6 weeks later introduced this feature as an extension to its emulation of [`DECSCUSR`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q.1D81):

> extend DECSCUSR to provide a way to set the cursor to a vertical bar (patch by Paul Bolle).

documented as follows:

```
CSI Ps SP q
          Set cursor style (DECSCUSR), VT520.
            Ps = 0  ⇒  blinking block.
            Ps = 1  ⇒  blinking block (default).
            Ps = 2  ⇒  steady block.
            Ps = 3  ⇒  blinking underline.
            Ps = 4  ⇒  steady underline.
            Ps = 5  ⇒  blinking bar, xterm.
            Ps = 6  ⇒  steady bar, xterm.
```

As indicated in a similar question ([*Customize vim cursor style under Mac OS X Terminal*](https://superuser.com/questions/712098/customize-vim-cursor-style-under-mac-os-x-terminal), July 2017) you can set vim's variables to use those escape sequences:

```
let &t_SI="\033[6 q" " start insert mode (steady bar, xterm)
let &t_EI="\033[1 q" " end insert mode
```